# how to align the last line in a paragraph centered seperately from the rest of the paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to set the entire paragraph fully justified, with the last line only centered.
I tried using "shift-enter" and then centering, but that centered the entire paragraph.

This is how it looks now (with just "shift-enter"):
[image]

This is how it looks when i do "shift-enter" and then center:
[image: this]
(styles also affect the entire paragraph)
if i do not use "shift-enter", the second to last line becomes right aligned (in right to left mode)

Comment: When I do this I add an extra line space or two at the end of the first part, align the second part and then go back to the line breaks at the beginning of the line and delete with the Delete Key (not Backspace).  That normally works - see if it works for you

Comment: thanks, I tried it. As long as there is nothing other than a line break ("shift-enter") separating the lines, the alignment merges.

Comment: Have you tried using a centre tab on the last line?

Comment: So is your problem solve?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since the alignment applies to the whole paragraph.

You may solve the problem by:

- Use multiple paragraphs with multiple alignments, while using a style that
  suppresses inter-paragraphs spacing
- Use tabs and manual line-ends to position the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can Separate the last line by **"Shift+Enter"** AND **"Space"** AND **"TAB"**.

This will remain all paragraph lines with justified alignment, beside the last line that will be alined according the TAB.

***Step by Step actions -***

In paragraph:

- In alignment: set justified.
- In tabs: Add centered tab (┴) at the middle on the paragraph line.

Now, you can handle the last line in your paragraph as following:

- Go to the start of the last line in the paragraph.
- Press Shift+Enter.
- Press Space.
- Press TAB.